# JAVA - Changing non static Class Field in Member Enum's Function

Tags: java, oop, enums, fsm

I am trying to implement an FSM in Java.
I have an FSM Class, which has a String field message, and an ENUM to manage the bot states.
Here's a sample code.

```
public class fsmBot
{
    public String message;

    public enum BotStates
    {
        greeting
        {
            @Override
            public void message()
            {
                message = "Hi";
            }

            @Override
            public String nextState()
            {
                String nxtState = BotStates.state1.name();
                return nxtState;
            }
        },
        state1
        {
            @Override
            public void message()
            {
                fsmApplyLeave.message = "How are you?";
            }

            @Override
            public String nextState()
            {
                String nxtState = BotStates.state1.name();
                return nxtState;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

But, here I am getting an error when I am accessing String message, a field of my class fsmBot, in functions greeting() of the enum BotStates. I could make it work by making message static, but I require multiple instances of this fsmBot class running.
Is there any way to do this?

*Edit1-
Eclipse gives the following error in the editor - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field message

Comment: enums are static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enum`s are static classes, so you could do something like this:

```
public class fsmBot
{
    public String message;

    public enum BotStates
    {
        greeting
        {
            @Override
            public void message(fsmBot bot)
            {
                bot.message = "Hi";
            }

            @Override
            public String nextState()
            {
                String nxtState = state1.name();
                return nxtState;
            }
        },
        state1
        {
            @Override
            public void message(fsmBot bot)
            {
                bot.message = "How are you?";
            }

            @Override
            public String nextState()
            {
                String nxtState = state1.name();
                return nxtState;
            }
        };

        public abstract void message(fsmBot bot);
        public abstract String nextState();
    }
}
```